# Exchange 2010 SP1 Non-Standard Ports

Tags: exchange-2010

I'm doing a small trial of Exchange Server at work, and I am having a few issues with associated ports on OWA.

I am being asked to use a different port for SSL, so I don't cause any conflicts with existing sites. I modified the bindings in IIS to use 4443 instead of 443 for ssl, and modified the address in the EMC, and it doesn't seem to want to work. Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft really *really* wants you to stay on TCP/443 for SSL, as that's where Outlook and any ActiveSync clients are hard coded to find it. You'll have better luck binding a second IP address to your IIS/OWA server and binding OWA on the new IP.

Comment: I agree with this.  Use separate IPs to avoid port conflicts, don't try to run Exchange on non-standard ports.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the IIS should do the trick.

Comment: Tried, didn't work.